# Limit number of entries in a list after its filtered

Tags: nunjucks

I have a list where I need to limit the number of entries that are **already filtered by a tag**. Since I need the limit to happen **after the entries are filtered**, I can't use " | limit(10)" as that only works in the for loop, not in the if statement.
The problem with limiting before filtering is that it only checks as many entries as the limit tells it to, so if there is no match in that number of entries, I get 0 entries as a result... which is not what I'm looking for, I need to first 10 entries that has the tag that I need to filter with.

This is what I have right now, entries show up, sorting works, filtering works:

```
---
pagecategory: 'potato'
---

{%- for review in collections.partner | sort(false, false, 'data.order_on_page') -%}
{% if review.data.tags.includes(pagecategory) %}

<p>{{review.data.title}}</p>

{% endif %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

**entries can have multiple tags** so I can't check for exact match to the 'pagecategory'.

I've searched the nunjucks documentation as well as all around the net, but I only found solutions that are the other way around - limiting the number of entries before they are filtered - that is not going to work.
How can I limit after filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works if data.tags.includes() is a custom tag filter:

```
eleventyConfig.addFilter('filterByTag', (posts, tag) => posts.filter(p => p.data.tags.includes(tag)))
```

so theres no need for if statement:

```
{%- for review in collections.partner | filterByTag(pagecategory) | limit(settings.list_limit) | sort(false, false, 'data.order_on_page') -%}
 
<p>{{review.data.title}}</p>

{% endif %}
{%- endfor -%}
```